# How getchar() function output

Tags: c++, getchar

I want to understand how is `getchar()` function is working here?

I read `getchar()` returns the next character from `stdin`, or `EOF` if the end of file is reached.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int decimal;
    while(!isdigit(decimal=getchar()));
    cout<<decimal;
}
```

I give input 25. It outputs 50. I don't understand why? 
How is it giving 50.

Comment: There is a difference between a digit character and an integer. `getchar` returns the character 2 and storing this into an int results in the encoding value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`getchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) reads a single character from the input stream and returns it's value. In your case, that is the character `'2'`. Most implementations (including yours it seems) use [ASCII encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/) where the character `'2'` has the value `50`. The value assigned to `decimal` is therefore `50`. Since `decimal` is an `int`, `std::cout` interprets it as a numeric value and prints it accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? I've been told that most use UTF-8.

Comment: @Chipster Well, UTF-8's first 128 characters correspond to ASCII encoding. I know most implementations are compatible with ASCII, but I'm not sure what portion of those are UTF-8 or ASCII.

Comment: [According to Google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#/media/File:Utf8webgrowth.svg), utf-8 is more widely used since 2008

Answer (score 2):

`decimal` is storing the first digit character it finds, which happens to be `'2'`. You're storing the value to an `int`, so `cout` outputs the ordinal value of `decimal`. The ASCII ordinal value of `'2'` is `50`. You never even reached the `5` you entered.

Simple fix to make it display the character, not the ordinal value, would be to change the output code to:

```
cout << (char)decimal;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter `25` it reads first character from this input. And first character is `2` here. ASCII value of `2` is `50`. That's why you get `50` at the output.

If you want to see `2` at the output use like this

`cout << (char) decimal << endl;`

Here type-casting `50` into character. That is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

**The C library function int getchar(void) gets a character (an unsigned char) from stdin.**

Moreover, decimal is an integer type and isdigit(decimal) will check the character at ASCII decimal position.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int decimal;
    while(!isdigit(decimal=getchar()));\\when you input 25. It first gets 2.
    \\ 2 gets stored as 50 inside decimal
    \\ isdigit() is called which returns true for 50 which is ASCII of 2 and while breaks
    cout<<decimal; \\ 50 is printed here. Type cast it to print 2. 
}
```